# "Middle kingdom", "Middle Earth" (Lotharingia, Lord of the Rings) in Latin

Tags: contemporary-latin, literature-request

Please "Middle kingdom", "Middle Earth" in Latin please :)

[image: Terra media]

Answer (score 4):

Terra Media is one translation of "Middle Earth" into Latin. Regnum Medium is a translation of "Middle Kingdom". We are using the noun "terra" to mean Earth (cf. terracotta, "baked earth") and "regnum" to mean kingdom. We are using the adjective "medius, -a, -um" to mean middle.

We can also reverse the order, and get Media Terra and Medium Regnum.

In Portuguese, the phrase "Middle Earth" is translated as Terra Média. In Spanish, it is translated as Tierra Media. Since Portuguese and Spanish are Romance languages that derive from Latin, this offers some evidence that the Latin translation would be Terra Media.